# Angular 6 - Input field mask

Tags: javascript, angular6, angular-directive

I want to mask the input field line 123-456-7890, i want to write angular directive the directive is working fine but the problem is i have mask only in text field not in model

component

`test: string;`

template

```
<input type="text" name="test" [(ngModel]="test" myCustomDirective />
```

Its displays like - 123-456-7890 and model also contain '-' i want the '-' in input box and not in model binding.

Please suggest me how to do.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know if that possible since the value will be the same in both sides, however have you tried just replace the - using the replace function and store the final value in a diferent place?    `test.replace(/-/g, '')`

Comment: For that , u cannot use text box with (-) values as far As I know. I suggest to create a new Component which will render 3 text boxes with out a border and keep a border to the parent container of those textboxes, and get the value

Comment: i am generating the field dynamically. so i cant do both the approach. i want to write a directive